# Get Notified When User Starts to Drive (CoreMotion)

Tags: swift, background-process, core-motion

I would like to send a notification to the user whenever he/she starts driving using `CoreMotion`. I can use `CoreMotion` to see what the user is doing while my app is on like so...

```
let activityManager = CMMotionActivityManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    activityManager.startActivityUpdates(to: .main) { (activity) in
        guard let activity = activity else {
            return
        }

        if activity.automotive {
            print("Driving")
        }

        if activity.stationary {
            print("Not Moving")

        }
    }
}
```

}

But how would I be able to detect the change to `activity.automotive` in the background to send a notification to the user even if my app is not on?